# Window's dll for mono

Tags: c#, linux, dll, mono

i want to use some functions of kernel32.dll (like GetSystemTime) in mono .i know that mono doesn't have kernel32.dll. but i want to know if there is some library in mono that has the functions of kernel32.dll which are compatible in mono.

Comment: Any reason you want to use `GetSystemTime` rather than just `DateTime.UtcNow` or the like? I would try to find managed equivalents as far as possible.

Comment: No, there is no such equivalent. You'll have to consider each case individually. Is it absolutely necessary you're making API calls to kernel32.dll? Maybe if you told us a bit more about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Mono is supposed to be multi platform. So anything platform specific has to be done the regular way, with P/Invoke, limiting yourself to a certain platform, or having special code for each platform your application runs on.

Comment: I would stick to Jon's advice and check whether a managed implementation already exists.